# How are proteins formed?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, proteins, amino-acids

Somewhere, I have read that we need to consume proteins to make amino acids to make new proteins. What does it suggest? How do we make proteins from proteins?

Comment: I suggest you have a read of the articles on protein and protein metabolism on Wikipedia :) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_metabolism) This is a really broad topic and it's best if you study it up yourself.

Comment: Let me know If I'm right with the phrase "proteins that we consume form new proteins that are different". I'm looking for a simple explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, yes, "proteins that we consume form new proteins that are different".

The processes are each of them topics for themselves. In short, consumed proteins are digested by [peptidases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptidase) (enzymes) in the stomach, breaking them down into their consituent [amino acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid). These are absorbed in the gut and transported in the blood to all cells. These take up amino acids and attach them to [tRNA molecules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tRNA) which are used in [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28biology%29) to form new body proteins.

Comment: Very elegantly worded.

Answer (score 3):

You ingest daily dietary protein which your body [hydrolyzes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_hydrolysis) to get all the building blocks for other proteins (amino acids).

Also, from diet you can get [essential amino acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid) that cannot be synthesized *de novo* by the organism which is more economical than amino acid synthesis. Other amino acids can be constructed by metabolic processes.